# ArrayList Bubblesort with strings

Tags: java, string, bubble-sort

The sorting is not working, it doesn't sort the names by the alphabet, I wrote a bubble sort algorithm with int and it worked fine. Can you help me? Is something wrong with the compareTo() method?

```
public ArrayList<FootballPlayer> sortByNames(ArrayList<FootballPlayer> pList)
    {
        FootballPlayer z;
        for(int i=0; i<pList.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<pList.size()-i-1;j++)
            {
                if((pList.get(i).getName()).compareTo(pList.get(j+1).getName())>0)
                {
                    z = pList.get(j);
                    pList.set(j, pList.get(j+1));
                    pList.set(j+1,z);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<pList.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(pList.get(i).getName()+";");
            System.out.println("");
        }
         return pList;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are comparing pList.get(i) to pList.get(j+1), but then you are swapping pList.get(j) with pList.get(j+1).  I believe you should be comparing the jth element with the j+1 th element.

Comment: Thank You, I was so deep in it, that I overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is **not BubbleSort**! Check [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) or event a bit more advanced [Cocktail shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort).

```
public static void bubbleSort(List<String> pList) {
    boolean done = false;

    for (int i = pList.size(); !done; i--) {
        done = true;

        for (int j = 0; j + 1 < i; j++) {
            if (pList.get(j).compareTo(pList.get(j + 1)) <= 0)
                continue;

            done = false;
            String tmp = pList.get(j);
            pList.set(j, pList.get(j + 1));
            pList.set(j + 1, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
List<String> pList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    pList.add(String.valueOf(i));

Collections.shuffle(pList);

System.out.println(pList);  // [0, 6, 7, 9, 5, 8, 4, 1, 3, 2]
bubbleSort(pList);
System.out.println(pList);  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Ok. Let it be so :-)